# c# (and maybe unity) - why is singleton not instantiated?

Tags: c#, singleton

I listened to the youtube unity tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCqOnchV4V0&t=2491s, in which it talked about defining singleton (at 59:29) like this:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameManager Instance { get; private set; }
    int scoreCount=0;
    //...
}
//when using the instance:
class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    //...
    GameManager.Instance.scoreCount++;
    //...
}
```

This method works in the first small unity game I made. However, when I use it the second time I failed to create an instance. Thus I decided to test it again.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class classiii
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            int result = Int32.Parse(input);
            Console.WriteLine(Program.Instance.A(result));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        public static Program Instance { get; private set; }

        int firstNum = 5;
        public int A(int tmp)
        {
            return firstNum + tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

So why is this not working? Why is it working in the first unity project?

Comment: `Instance` is never initialized.

Comment: "_why is singleton not instantiated?_" Well, yeah, where in your code do you instantiate the singleton instance, or where do you instruct some other Unity/.NET function/facility to instantiate that singleton for you? Can you point me to it?

Comment: Remember, the type of your _Instance_ singletons (whether GameManager or Program) are reference types (any class is a reference type). When you just declare a field without assigning some value to it (i.e., an instance of GameManager or Program), it is being initialized with the default value of the corresponding type. For any reference types, this default value is `null`. In your first Unity example, there is somewhere some code in your project that is responsible for creating the GameManager instance. In your second code example, there is nothing creating the singleton...

Comment: A console app is not Unity.   However. Chances it worked in your game because it was on a gameobject. So it did get instantiated.

Comment: Thank you guys! I realized what my script's problem is!